# Named Credential auto-generate aws sig4 not working for s3 'versions'

Tags: namedcredentials, aws, header, amazon-s3

### Main issue:

I get a signature mismatch error (403 forbidden) when trying to hit the REST api for s3 using the `versions` action ([ListObjectVersions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/list-obj-version-enabled-bucket.html#ListingtheObjectsinaVersioningEnabledBucket)). It seems to me that this may be an error with how the auto-generated auth header is being generated, but I'm looking for clues on how to debug and/or fix this.

The exact error is:

> `<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>`

The odd thing about this is everything was working for the [ListObjectsv2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html#API_ListObjectsV2_RequestSyntax) (`list-type=2` in the REST request). The only thing I changed in my url was to replace `list-type=2` with `versions`. I'm changing the action because I need to grab all versions of an object (file) instead of just all current objects.

I checked bucket policies and IAM permissions and verified the user's access locally, so that leads me to believe it's an issue with the auto-generated auth Header within Salesforce. The user has `ListBucket` and `ListBucketVersions` permissions.

Sample new url with the error:

```
https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/?versions&prefix=myFolderPath
```

Sample old url that works:

```
https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/?list-type=2&prefix=myFolderPath
```

where `myFolderPath` is UTF-8 url encoded, and ends in a slash (before encoding).

The Apex classes that use the named credential are on api version 47, but are being migrated to 50 right now. It appears that the auto-generate feature was added in version 46.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to chalk this up to being an issue with the AWS S3 REST API. [Their documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectVersions.html) clearly shows the following in their example:

```
GET /?versions&delimiter=Delimiter&encoding-type=EncodingType&key-marker=KeyMarker&max-keys=MaxKeys&prefix=Prefix&version-id-marker=VersionIdMarker HTTP/1.1
Host: Bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-expected-bucket-owner: ExpectedBucketOwner
```

But in reality, it expects it in this format (using my original example):

```
https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/?prefix=myFolderPath&versions=1
```

The query parameters have to be in alphabetical order (ASCII sort order) and the `versions` parameter has to have `=1` on the end.

I saw that the [sig4 signature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html) has to have the query parameters in order, but it didn't say anything about the actual url sent to amazon needing to have parameters in sort order.

Comment: I have submitted an AWS documentation update request.